# Sharing Android Market Statistics with another account

Tags: android, google-play

Is there any way within the Android Marketplace to share sales statistics of any/all of my apps with another Google account? I'm looking for something roughly analogous to adding a "Sales" user to my account in iTunes Connect: I want to be able to share the sales statistics for my app with my marketing specialist, without necessarily giving him the ability to publish apps. (Or read my email!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do that right now.

Comment: Darn. That's kind of what I suspected, but I held out hope that someone else had come across (and solved) this problem before.