# Share Android app Play store statistics

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way to share download statistics that Google Play Console provides for a specific app?

Clients app is released with my account and I would like them to see some information, but I don't want to share my Google account.

I found a similar question here: [Sharing Android Market Statistics with another account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819898/sharing-android-market-statistics-with-another-account)

That question is 8 years old, and I hope the answer changed in the meantime.